# Python - create tuples from list

Tags: python, list, dictionary, tuples, list-comprehension

given this `dictionary`:

```
sql_playlists={
'user1':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 1': 1.0},
'user2':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 2': 1.0},
'user3':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 3': 1.0},
'user4':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 4': 1.0},
'user5':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 4': 1.0}}
```

I can create data tuples of `keys`and `values`like this:

```
sqltuples = [(k1,k2,v2) for k1,v1 in sql_playlists.items()
             for k2,v2 in v1.items()]
```

which outputs:

```
[(u'user1', u'Make You Feel My Love', 1.0), (u'user1', u'I See Fire', 1.0), (u'user', u'High And Dry', 1.0), (u'user1', u'Fake Plastic Trees', 1.0), (u'user1', u'One', 1.0), (u'user1', u'Goodbye My Lover', 1.0), (u'user1', u'No Surprises', 1.0)]
```

for each user.

but what if `sql_playlist` is a `list`, the same data structure but inside `[]`, and not a `dictionary`?

EDIT: the list

```
sql_playlists=[{
'user1':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 1': 1.0},
'user2':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 2': 1.0},
'user3':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 3': 1.0},
'user4':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 4': 1.0},
'user5':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 4': 1.0}}]
```

how do I adapt the `list comprehension` in order to produce the same `tuples` from the list?

this works for the first user:

```
sqltuples = [(k1,k2,v2) for k1,v1 in sql_playlists[0].items()
             for k2,v2 in v1.items()]
```

but i want for all users.

Comment: Can you show what the list would look?

Comment: @PaulRooney I've edited it for you

Comment: Your second code example produces the same output as the first. The only difference is the whole thing is wrapped in a list. So `sql_playlists[0]` gets you to the exact same dictionary object.

Comment: @PaulRooney The first code example produces tuples for all users, the second only for the first user.

Comment: the NEW list you provided is the same dict wraped in the list (as in a list with single dictionary as entry), if that's the case then you already gave the answer yourself :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you mean array of dictionaries: 
`sql_playlists=[
    {'user1':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 1': 1.0}},
    {'user2':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 2': 1.0}},
    {'user3':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 3': 1.0}},
    {'user4':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 4': 1.0}},
    {'user5':{'Karma Police':1.0,'Roxanne':1.0,'Sonnet':1.0,'We Will Rock You':1.0,'Song 4': 1.0}}]`

then:

`sqltuples = [(k1,k2,v2) for vlist in sql_playlists for k1,v1 in vlist.items() for k2,v2 in v1.items()]`

you should note that this will produce the tuples in different order because the sorting is preserved when enumerating lists but not dicts